# Approve Time Card Summaries filter customization

Tags: acumatica

I'm customizing the Approve Time Card Summaries screen to do the following:

1.) Add a checkbox to the filter section

2.) When this checkbox is checked, don't show the 'Approved' rows in the grid.

I've added a cache extension with a new unbound boolean field, and added the checkbox to the filter / header section of the screen.

What I'm wondering is - Is there an IEnumerable method (can I use 'summary'?) that can check that header filter field and only yield return the rows that pass the filter test?  If so, I'm not sure what the syntax would be to do this.

Or - would it be better to rewrite the Summary view select statement in the Graph extension with the added where clause?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this.  In the Graph extension, I rewrote the 'Summary' view and then used the IEnumerable 'summary' delegate to return only the rows where it meets the checkbox criteria I set up.  To wit:

```
        public PXSelectJoin<EPSummaryApprove
        , LeftJoin<EPEarningType, On<EPEarningType.typeCD, Equal<EPSummaryApprove.earningType>>>
        , Where2<Where<EPSummaryApprove.taskApproverID, Equal<Current<EPSummaryFilter.approverID>>, Or<Where<EPSummaryApprove.taskApproverID, IsNull, And<EPSummaryApprove.approverID, Equal<Current<EPSummaryFilter.approverID>>>>>>
            , And2<Where<EPSummaryApprove.weekId, GreaterEqual<Current<EPSummaryFilter.fromWeek>>, Or<Current<EPSummaryFilter.fromWeek>, IsNull>>
                , And2<Where<EPSummaryApprove.weekId, LessEqual<Current<EPSummaryFilter.tillWeek>>, Or<Current<EPSummaryFilter.tillWeek>, IsNull>>
                    , And2<Where<EPSummaryApprove.projectID, Equal<Current<EPSummaryFilter.projectID>>, Or<Current<EPSummaryFilter.projectID>, IsNull>>
                        , And2<Where<EPSummaryApprove.projectTaskID, Equal<Current<EPSummaryFilter.projectTaskID>>, Or<Current<EPSummaryFilter.projectTaskID>, IsNull>>
                            , And<Where<EPSummaryApprove.employeeID, Equal<Current<EPSummaryFilter.employeeID>>, Or<Current<EPSummaryFilter.employeeID>, IsNull>>
                                >
                            >
                        >
                    >
                >
            >
        > Summary;

    protected IEnumerable summary()
    {
        var epsf = (EPSummaryFilter)Base.Filter.Cache.Current;
        var epse =   PXCache<EPSummaryFilter>.GetExtension<EPSummaryFilterExt>(epsf);

        foreach(var res in Base.Summary.Select())
        {
            var sum = (EPSummaryApprove)res;

            if (epse != null)
            {
                if (epse.ExcludeApproved == true)
                {
                    if (sum.IsApprove != true)
                    {
                        yield return res;
                    }
                }
                else
                    yield return res;
            }
            else
                yield return res;
        }
    }
```